# 'Invalid property value' in Div background-color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use one of Bootstrap examples: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

The following code is inserted into the navbar-inner div:

```
    <div class="logo">
        <div class="quadratLogo">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

Styled as:

```
    .logo {
      font-size: 24px;
      font-family: 'Arial';
      min-width: 500px;
    }

    .quadratLogo {
        width:24px;
        height:20px;
        border-radius:0px 4px 0px 4px;
        background-color: ff0000;
        float:left;
    }
```

Can you tell why quadratLogo div is invisible and the background-color property of quadratLogo is seen as unvalid by Chrome?

Comment: Allow me to introduce my little friend:  http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: For me, the issue was rgb. must use hex.

Answer (score 9):

That's a valid color - but you forgot to include a `#` symbol before the hex value.

```
.quadratLogo {
     width:24px;
     height:20px;
     border-radius:0px 4px 0px 4px;
     background-color: #ff0000;
            /* --------^ */
}
```

Comment: My browser admits it without the hash and actually it works [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/256764/bootstrap/src/tstout.html).I think it's something to do with the styles from Bootstrap.

Comment: Well when you say `"background-color property of quadratLogo is seen as unvalid by Chrome?"` do you mean it just isn't showing up or you're seeing an error in the dev. tools? If its the former, its probably a specificity issue

Comment: Invalid property is how the Chrome inspector identified my background-colour parameter. I also tried with @orange, which looks like a valid value in Bootstrap but it didn't work neither. Excuse me but I'm a newbie and I don't understand the term 'specificity'

Answer (score 5):

Your `background-color` property is incorrect.

it should be `background-color: #ff0000;` or set the proper color name

Read more about [background-color](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp)

Comment: My browser admits it without the hash and actually it works [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/256764/bootstrap/src/tstout.html).I think it's something to do with the styles from Bootstrap

Comment: @naio: if you use firebug and inspect the element, you can see it is  `#ff0000`. Try in `IE` you might have issues !!